# Return a sorted combination of two arrays

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, methods

My method should return the combination of array "a" and "b" returning the combination as a ordered array "c".

For a[5] and b[4,6] c[] should return [4,5,6]

In the end for these case my code is returning [4,5],i think there is a problem in the sorting method that i can't see.

```
package combinaum;
import java.util.Scanner;
/**
 *
 * @author 201627010262
 */
public class CombinaUm {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
   Scanner teclado = new Scanner (System.in);
   int n1 = teclado.nextInt();
   int n2 = teclado.nextInt();
   int[] a = new int [n1];
   int[] b = new int [n2];
   for(int i = 0; i < n1; i++)
   {
       a[i] = teclado.nextInt();
   }
   for(int i = 0; i < n2; i++)
   {
       b[i] = teclado.nextInt();
   }

  System.out.println(Arrays.toString(Combine(a, b, n1, n2)));
}

public static int Combine(int a[], int b[], int n1, int n2)
{  
    int e = 0;
    int d = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int n3 = n1+n2; 
    int [] c = new int [n3];

    while(e < a.length && d <b.length )
    {
        if(a[e] < b[d])
        {
           c[i] = a[e];
           e++;
           i++;
        }
        else
        {
            c[i] = b[d];
            d++;
            i++;
        }
    }
    while(e < a.length)
    {
        e++;
    }
    while(d <b.length)
    {
        d++;
    }

     return Arrays.copyOf(c, i);
}

}
```

Comment: Did you mean to return `c[i]` at the end of your method?  Or to return all of `c`?  If you want to return all of `c`, you'll have to change the method's return type to `int[]`, and also change the way you print the returned value.  Do you know about `Arrays.toString`?

Comment: Yeah, i should print the sorted combination of a[] and b[], i edited my question to be more clear, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to pass `n1` and `n2` parameters. Arrays know their size, and you can get it using `a.length` and `b.length`. Also you want to return `int[]` to have the whole array instead of single `int`.

```
public static int[] Combine(int a[], int b[]) {
    int[] c = Arrays.copyOf(a, a.length + b.length);
    System.arraycopy(b, 0, c, a.length, b.length);
    return c;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the insight, i edited my question to be more clear, i need c[] to be the sorted combination of a[] and b[].

Comment: This doesn't do quite the same thing as the original code was trying to do.  The original does some kind of sorting, so that if `a` and `b` are both sorted ascending, then `c` will be too.